EV3 Micropython thread is stuck
I start the program in VSCode on the brick and it's stuck on the thread and does nothing and I'm do not know how. I use deamons to have background processes for monitoring and use the data parallel.
#!/usr/bin/env pybricks-micropython

from pybricks.hubs import EV3Brick as brick
from pybricks.ev3devices import (Motor, ColorSensor,
                                  UltrasonicSensor)
from pybricks.parameters import (Port, Stop, Direction, Button, Color,
                                 SoundFile, ImageFile, Align)
from pybricks.tools import (print, wait, StopWatch, DataLog)
from pybricks.media.ev3dev import Font
import threading
import time  # Importiere die time Bibliothek

from modules import color_module  # Importiere das color_module

# Initialisiere EV3-Stein und Sensoren
recorded_data = color_module.measure_color_values(1)  # Messung für 1 Sekunde
COLOR_THRESHOLDS = color_module.process_color_data(recorded_data)
ev3 = brick()
left_motor = Motor(Port.B, Direction.CLOCKWISE)
right_motor = Motor(Port.C, Direction.CLOCKWISE)
medium_motor = Motor(Port.D)
color_sensor = ColorSensor(Port.S3)
ultrasonic_sensor = UltrasonicSensor(Port.S2)


# Initialisiere globale Variablen
round_number = 0
start_time = 0
all_rounds_completed = False
r, g, b = color_sensor.rgb()

# PID-Parameter
Kp = 0
Ki = 0
Kd = 0

# Stoppuhr initialisieren
stopwatch = StopWatch()

# Datenprotokoll initialisieren
data_log = DataLog('time', 'angle', 'color', 'correction')
# Debugging: Ausgabe der Farbschwellenwerte
print("COLOR_THRESHOLDS:", COLOR_THRESHOLDS)

# Debugging: Ausgabe der RGB-Werte des Farbsensors
print("RGB:", color_sensor.rgb())


# Funktion zum Starten des Countdowns und Abspielen von Sound
def start_countdown_thread():
    global start_time
    countdown = 3
    ev3.light.on(Color.RED)
    while countdown > 0:
        ev3.screen.clear()
        ev3.screen.draw_text(60, 50, str(countdown))
        if countdown == 3:
            ev3.speaker.say("drei")
        elif countdown == 2:
            ev3.speaker.say("zwei")
            ev3.light.on(Color.ORANGE)
        elif countdown == 1:
            ev3.speaker.say("eins")
        wait(1000)
        countdown -= 1
    ev3.screen.clear()
    ev3.light.on(Color.GREEN)
    ev3.speaker.say("Los")

# Automatische Einstellung der PID-Parameter mit Ziegler-Nichols-Methode
def auto_tune_pid():
    # Set initial parameters
    Kp = 1
    Ki = 0
    Kd = 0
    Ts = 0.1  # Sampling time

    # Set the step change for tuning
    step_change = 20

    # Initialize the system state and variables
    state = 'start'
    last_error = 0
    integral = 0
    derivative = 0  # Initialize derivative
    tuning_complete = False
    error = 0

    while not tuning_complete:
        if state == 'start':
            control_signal = Kp * step_change
            state = 'step_change'
        elif state == 'step_change':
            error = step_change - last_error
            integral += error * Ts
            derivative = (error - last_error) / Ts
            control_signal += Kp * error + Ki * integral + Kd * derivative

            if last_error > 0 and error < 0:
                Kc = 4 * Kp / step_change
                tuning_complete = True

        last_error = error

    # Berechne PID parameter mit der Ziegler-Nichols Methode
    Kp = 0.6 * Kc
    Ki = 2 * Kp / (0.5 * Ts)
    Kd = Kp * (0.125 * Ts)

    return Kp, Ki, Kd


# Funktion zum Ausführen des PID-Algorithmus
def PID():
    global Kp, Ki, Kd
    Ts = 150
    error = 0
    integral = 0  # Initialisiere integral
    last_error = 0  # Initialisiere last_error
    for _ in range(1000):
        # Farbe basierend auf Schwellenwerten klassifizieren
        if r < COLOR_THRESHOLDS['black'][0] and g < COLOR_THRESHOLDS['black'][1] and b < COLOR_THRESHOLDS['black'][2]:
            color = 'black'
        elif r > COLOR_THRESHOLDS['red'][0] and g < COLOR_THRESHOLDS['red'][1] and b < COLOR_THRESHOLDS['red'][2]:
            color = 'rot'
        elif r < COLOR_THRESHOLDS['green'][0] and g > COLOR_THRESHOLDS['green'][1] and b < COLOR_THRESHOLDS['green'][2]:
            color = 'grün'
        elif r < COLOR_THRESHOLDS['blue'][0] and g < COLOR_THRESHOLDS['blue'][1] and b > COLOR_THRESHOLDS['blue'][2]:
            color = 'blau'
        elif r > COLOR_THRESHOLDS['yellow'][0] and g > COLOR_THRESHOLDS['yellow'][1] and b < COLOR_THRESHOLDS['yellow'][2]:
            color = 'gelb'
        else:
            color = 'unbekannt'
       # Debugging: Ausgabe der Farbklassifizierung
        print("Color Classification:", color)
        # Fehler basierend auf Farbe berechnen
        integral += error
        derivative = error - last_error
        correction = (Kp * error + Ki * integral + Kd * derivative) * -1
        
         # Daten aus dem PID drucken
        print("Error:", error)
        print("Integral:", integral)
        print("Derivative:", derivative)
        print("Correction:", correction)

        # Korrektur auf Motoren anwenden
        left_motor.run(Ts + correction)
        right_motor.run(Ts - correction)

        last_error = error

        wait(10)

    # Optimale PID-Parameter berechnen
    run_pid_with_calculated_parameters()

# Funktion zum Ausführen des PID-Algorithmus mit berechneten Parametern
def run_pid():
    while True:
        print("123")
        PID()  # Hier wird die PID-Funktion aufgerufen
        print("123")


# Funktion zum Ausführen des PID-Algorithmus mit berechneten Parametern
def run_pid_with_calculated_parameters():
    global Kp, Ki, Kd
    Kp, Ki, Kd = auto_tune_pid()
    print("PID-Parameter:", Kp, Ki, Kd)  # Debugging-Ausgabe der PID-Parameter
    # Starten Sie den PID-Thread
    pid_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_pid)
    pid_thread.daemon = True
    pid_thread.start()
    print("PID-Thread gestartet")  # Debugging-Ausgabe, um zu überprüfen, ob der Thread gestartet wurde


# Rundenfunktionen

# Funktion zum Ausführen von Runde 1
def round_1():
    global round_number
    ev3.speaker.say("Runde 1")
    while True:
        # Debugging: Ausgabe des aktuellen Farbwerts
        print("Color:", color_sensor.rgb())
        if color_sensor.color() == Color.GREEN:
            ev3.speaker.say("Eins")
            break

# Funktion für Runde 2
def round_2():
    global round_number
    ev3.speaker.say("Runde 2")
    while True:
        if ultrasonic_sensor.distance() < 100:
            pick_up_palette()
        if color_sensor.color() == Color.BLUE:
            break
    round_number += 1
    
# Funktion zum Ausführen von Runde 3
def round_3():
    global round_number
    ev3.speaker.say("Runde 3")
    while True:
        if ultrasonic_sensor.distance() < 100:
            ev3.speaker.say("Drei")
            break

# Funktion zum Ausführen von Runde 4
def round_4():
    global round_number
    ev3.speaker.say("Runde 4")

    while True:
        if color_sensor.color() == Color.GREEN:
            ev3.speaker.say("Good Job")
            break

# Funktion zum Ausführen von Runde 5 (Abkühlungsrunde)
def round_5():
    global round_number
    ev3.speaker.say("Abkühlungsrunde")
    while True:
        if color_sensor.color() == Color.BLUE:
            break
        elif color_sensor.color() == Color.RED:
            ev3.speaker.say("Good Job")
            left_motor.stop()
            right_motor.stop()
            break

def pick_up_palette():
    while True:
        pass

# Funktion zum Starten der Zeitmessung
def start_time_measurement():
    global start_time
    start_time = stopwatch.time()

# Funktion zum Anzeigen der vergangenen Zeit
def show_elapsed_time():
    global start_time
    elapsed_time = stopwatch.time() - start_time
    ev3.screen.load_image(ImageFile.SQUARE_SMALL)
    ev3.screen.draw_text(60, 50, "Zeit: " + str(elapsed_time))

# Funktion für alle Runden
def all_rounds():
    global round_number
    start_countdown_thread()
    start_time_measurement()
    run_pid_with_calculated_parameters()
    round_number = 1
    while round_number <= 5:
        if round_number == 1:
            round_1()
        elif round_number == 2:
            round_2()
        elif round_number == 3:
            round_3()
        elif round_number == 4:
            round_4()
        elif round_number == 5:
            round_5()
            show_elapsed_time()
        round_number += 1

# Funktion für den Hintergrundprozess zur kontinuierlichen Farbüberwachung
def color_monitor():
    while True:
        recorded_data = color_module.measure_color_values(1)
        color_thresholds = color_module.process_color_data(recorded_data)
        time.sleep(1)

# Hintergrundprozess starten
color_monitor_thread = threading.Thread(target=color_monitor)
color_monitor_thread.daemon = True
color_monitor_thread.start()

# Hauptfunktion
def main():
    all_rounds()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


# color_module.py

from pybricks.hubs import EV3Brick as brick
from pybricks.ev3devices import ColorSensor
from pybricks.parameters import Port
from pybricks.tools import wait, StopWatch

# Globale Variablen und Objekte initialisieren
ev3 = brick()
color_sensor = ColorSensor(Port.S3)
stopwatch = StopWatch()

def measure_color_values(duration_seconds):
    """
    Misst die Farbwerte für eine bestimmte Dauer und gibt sie zurück.
    """
    recorded_data = []
    start_time = stopwatch.time()
    while stopwatch.time() - start_time < duration_seconds * 1000:
        r, g, b = color_sensor.rgb()
        color = color_sensor.color()

        # Daten protokollieren
        recorded_data.append({'time': stopwatch.time(), 'red': r, 'green': g, 'blue': b, 'color': color})

        # Kurze Pause vor der nächsten Messung
        wait(10)
    
    return recorded_data

def process_color_data(recorded_data):
    """
    Verarbeitet die aufgezeichneten Farbwerte und passt die Schwellenwerte dynamisch an.
    """
    # Berechne die Durchschnittswerte für rote, grüne und blaue Kanäle
    num_samples = len(recorded_data)
    sum_r = sum(sample['red'] for sample in recorded_data)
    sum_g = sum(sample['green'] for sample in recorded_data)
    sum_b = sum(sample['blue'] for sample in recorded_data)

    avg_r = sum_r / num_samples
    avg_g = sum_g / num_samples
    avg_b = sum_b / num_samples

    # Passe die Schwellenwerte dynamisch an
    COLOR_THRESHOLDS = {
        'black': (avg_r * 0.8, avg_g * 0.8, avg_b * 0.8),
        'red': (avg_r * 1.2, avg_g * 0.8, avg_b * 0.8),
        'green': (avg_r * 0.8, avg_g * 1.2, avg_b * 0.8),
        'blue': (avg_r * 0.8, avg_g * 0.8, avg_b * 1.2),
        'yellow': (avg_r * 1.2, avg_g * 1.2, avg_b * 0.8),
    }

    return COLOR_THRESHOLDS

This module just has a tempory table to dynamically assume the color when the light condition changes
I was debugging with a friend and I expected that using Self tuning PID for FLL robot kills the need to tune manually. It resulted in segerrors, but now I don't get any print statements from the console

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
